# Como verificar que la dll este fimada

Tags: c#

Hola actualmente estoy tratando de verificar si una dll y/o componente esta firmada mediante c#

Alguien tendra idea de como se pudiera realizar

Answer (score 0):

Buenas te dejo informacion que tal vez pueda ayudarte:

> Debe encontrar el [GUID](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_%C3%BAnico_global) de un objeto [COM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) definido en la DLL. A continuación, observe esta clave de registro:
>
> `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}\InprocServer32` 
>   Reemplace las x con el GUID.
>
> Debe tener un valor predeterminado que contenga la ruta completa a la DLL.

Aqui encontrè otro [link](https://blogs.msmvps.com/vipul/2006/01/27/Is-DLL-Registered/) con informacion para tu problema.

Agradeceria que indicaras si te fue de ayuda alguna de estas respuestas para de esta forma poder dar una respuesta mas exacta a la misma pregunta en un futuro.

Comment: Hola estoy viendo el link que me proporcionaste pero el detalle es saber que codigo debe de regresar si es que esta firmada la DLL

Comment: Estimado,  en el codigo del link es un boolean, retorna el nombre de la dll si esta firmado